# Vue.js does not seem to be updating the DOM on a variable change

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am fairly certain this is an extremely simple problem, but I have spent around 3 hours attempting to figure it out to no avail. If I bind a variable inside of a Vue object, i.e. `data: {x: a}` where a is some variable, and then I change the value of `a`, I was under the impression that it would change the value of `data.x` as well, no?

I'm currently attempting a `v-if`/`v-else` chain, with the if statement involving an inequality, but even after it should evaluate to `true`, what is displayed does not change. I made some sample code, and a JSFiddle to go with it.

```
<div id="app">
  <button v-if="unlocked">
    Unlocked
  </button>
  <button v-else-if="a >= b">
    Available
  </button>
  <button v-else>
    Unavailable
  </button>
  <span>{{a}}</span>
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
var x = {
    unlocked: false,
  a: 0,
  b: 10,
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    unlocked: x.unlocked,
    a: x.a,
    b: x.b
  },
});

function y() {
    x.a++;
  console.log(x.a);
}

var z = setInterval(y, 250);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ny5phzqe/

It increments the variable, but neither the text nor the displayed button change. Have I fundamentally misunderstood something about Vue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I bind a variable inside of a Vue object, i.e. data: {x: a} where a is some variable, and then I change the value of a, I was under the impression that it would change the value of data.x as well, no?

This misunderstanding is the reason for the trouble, and it is not related to Vue but to how Javascript and object references work.  To put it concisely: your statement is only true if `a` is an object.  In your example it is not, it's a primitive Number type.

Why does it matter?  Because in Javascript, *when a variable holds an object, it really only contains a reference to the object.  But when a variable holds a primitive type, it contains the actual value.*  This means multiple variables may hold references to the same object.

If `a` had been an object, then-- due to the nature of Javascript object references-- setting `{x: a}` would mean that `x` and `a` each store a **reference** to the same object.  You can think of this object as not belonging to either `x` or `a`, which are storing references to it.  If you were to then make changes to properties on this object, from either `x` or `a`, it would be reflected in both places.

But since `a` is a Number, then-- due to the nature of Javascript primitives-- setting `{x: a}` means that `x` receives a copy of `a`'s value as it is in that moment.  No references, no connection.  They both immediately contain completely separate primitive values.

Comment: This just made it click, thank you so much! I should simply set `data: {x: x}`, then? Or is this bad practice?

Comment: Welcome :)  As far as best practices:  realize `x` is laboriously replacing the component's data object, and `z` is replacing an event handler, all external to the component.  Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/sokjc47g/) to see how it should be done

Comment: For my actual project, a number of other functions are able to add to the equivalent of `x.a` in the fiddle, and there will be multiple 'groups' that will need to depend on the changing of `x.a`. Would I want to simply include a method to change every dependent Vue object as well when the variable changes? Or would it then be better to set it to the object?

Comment: Whenever something is dependent on the changing of a piece of component `data`, it typically calls for a `computed` property to be used.  If you want to link a rough fiddle with a broken example, I can try to correct it.

Comment: Sure, I'd appreciate that! Thank you again for all of the help.

Comment: I just realized I entirely misread what you said, I've just whipped the JSFiddle up now: https://jsfiddle.net/jLpfdu2n/ should do about what I'm currently doing, which works. Is this bad practice? One thing to note is that there easily might be dozens of these buttons at least, and at least 2 separate functions increasing `b` at their own rate, and at different times. `b` also may be increasing every 50ms, rather than 250ms.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get a notification for your reply.  This is bad practice for multiple reasons and I would recommend studying my link below carefully.  Because 1.) You have 2 Vue apps running, 2.) you should define variables and methods inside of the Vue framework rather than externally as globals, 3.) You should use lifecycle hooks where necessary.  And there are some other structural reasons too, such as using `v-for` instead of manually coding each button.  Here is the app in a structure that fits with the Vue way of doing things:  [jsfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/g5yht7k2/)

Comment: Oh, having multiple Vue apps running is a bad practice? Would I want to essentially wrap the entire body in a Vue app, then..? I'm going to have a number of various buttons that function somewhat like this in a fair few different locations. My other concern with defining the incrementing variable inside of the Vue app is that a *lot* of other things outside of Vue depend on this variable as well; would putting it inside the app cause issues with this? Lastly, all of the buttons will likely have different text, should I put the text in a variable in the app and still use `v-for`?

Comment: 1. Multi apps bad-- Generally unnecessary, yes.  Use components for extensibility,  2. Wrap body-- Yes, you can see how that looks in my fiddle.  Here it is again in case you didn't see [jsfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/g5yht7k2/), 3. Various buttons-- No problem, 4. Ah, if you have to use external code outside the app, then it's ok to define it globally, 5. Text in different variable-- Yes.  Check my fiddle to see where that property would be added.

Comment: I did see the fiddle! I just wanted to make sure that just adding it to the body tag was okay, as every example I've seen has only used specific divs. Thank you again for all of the help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: No problem!  It's probably best to use a div for mounting.

Comment: One question I just recently thought of: Rather than attach the vue object to a pointer like I did in my example, would it be better to have a method on, say, a 100ms loop, like in your fiddle, that updates its own value to match the global variable? Or just to keep it attached to that global variable?

Comment: I don't know because I don't know what you're trying to do with your app.  Maybe it would be good to create a new fiddle and ask another Stack question for it.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes and no. Vue will watch data.a, and update it directly but you are changing x.a and expecting data.a to update. That won't work.

Your flow of your code is roughly this:

1. Create object X
2. Create Vue instance
3. Initiate Vue with data property a with value x.a (0)
4. Define a function that increments x.a
5. Call the increment function (that manuplates x)

There is no "connection" or reactivity between data.a and x. Vue will update the view/template according to how data.a changes but you are never changing that value. You are changing x.a

Here's a working example of how to change data.a

```
new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      data: {
        unlocked: false,
        a: 0,
        b: 10
      },
      methods: {
        increment() {    
            this.a++;
            console.log(x.a);
        }    
      },
      mounted() {
        setInterval(this.increment, 1000)
        }
    });
```

Check out this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/m46sa3og/1/

Answer (score 1):

When you declare

```
a: x.a
```

You are assigning a initial value.

If you want to update the value, you need to do the change on the variable inside on the Vue Object. A best practice, with a method inside the component:

```
var myVue = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    unlocked: false,
    a: 0,
    b: 10
  },
  methods: {
     increment() {
        this.a++
        console.log(this.a)
     }
  }
});
myVue.increment()
console.log(myVue.a)
```

Comment: Oh! I guess I just somehow horribly misread one of the pages. One part of it, I took to mean that if you change the original variable, it changes the one in the Vue object as well, and visa versa. [This](http://prntscr.com/nplm9m) part in particular. Thank you for clarifying!